# Пояснения по задаче на списки haskell

Tags: списки, haskell

lookupTitle - это функция, которая выводит те Products, где в названии есть String. Так вот не совсем понимаю, как работает lookupTitles в последней строке, что такое p, xn?

```
data Product = Book String String | Casette String | Disk String String Int deriving (Eq,Show)

lookupTitle :: String -> [Product] -> Maybe Product
lookupTitle x [] = Nothing
lookupTitle x (p:ps) | (x == (getTitle(p))) = Just p
                 | otherwise = lookupTitle x ps

lookupTitles :: [String] -> [Product] -> [Maybe Product]
lookupTitles [] _ = []
lookupTitles _ [] = []
lookupTitles (x:xs) p = if xn == Nothing then (lookupTitles xs p) else xn :(lookupTitles xs p) 
                    where xn = (lookupTitle x p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` - список продуктов, как `p:ps` в `lookupTitle`. `xn` - результат поиска первого тайтла из списка тайтлов. Если тайтл не найден - пытаемся найти следующий в этом же списке продуктов, а если найден - предписываем его в начало возвращаемого списка и снова пытаемся найти следующий тайтл в списке продуктов.